# ¿como insertar ultimos 5 caracteres de una cadena?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hola lo que sucede es que tengo un sistema en asp.net y c# en el cual el usuario debe obligatoriamente ingresar 15 numeros en un textbox, pero solo se deben guardar los ultimos 5 de en un campo de base de datos.
Nose si haya alguna funcion de SQL para hacer eso, o pasar los ultimos digitos a una variable. Ya indague un poco pero no entiendo muy bien.

Encontre este codigo, pero me marca error

```
string cadena = codigo.Text;
string resultado = cadena.Substring(9, cadena.Length-4);
```

> error: El índice y la longitud deben hacer referencia a una ubicación en la cadena. Nombre del parámetro: length'

Comment: Simple, si ya tienes un tamaño fijo (es decir la cadena siempre va a ser de un mismo tamaño), basta con pasar el indice de inicio: ejemplo para tu caso `cadena.substring(10);` tomará el valor desde el indice 10 hasta el final del `string`.

Comment: @Andrespengineer me puedes dar un ejemplo? :C

Comment: `string resultado = cadena.Substring(10);` si tu string cadena es de longitud 15. Tomara desde 10 hasta 14. Es decir los ultimos 5 caracteres.

Comment: El problema de tu código es que no debe ser `cadena.Length - 4`, ya que el segundo parámetro indica la cantidad de caracteres que tomara a partir del primer parámetro. Lo que hará que si tu `string` cadena es de tamaño 15. Tomara desde 9, los siguientes 15-4 caracteres, es decir que estará tomando 11 caracteres a partir del 9, por lo que te causara el error que mencionas. Si lo quieres hacer de esa forma deberías hacer `cadena.Length - 9`, es decir `Substring(inicio, fin - inicio);`.

Comment: @Andrespengineer no dejas de tener razón, pero dado que siempre quiere 5 caracteres...por que no simplemente `cadena.Substring(10,5)`? Lo único es que debe siempre asegurarse de que `cadena` tiene 15 caracteres. O, como decías en tu comentario, simplemente `cadena.Substring(10)`. O `cadena.Substring(cadena.Length-5)`. O... bueno, ya paro :)

Comment: @Pikoh, también es una opción, pero mi recomendación para el autor de la pregunta es que haga las respectivas validaciones tanto para el `startIndex` como para el `count`, así evita una excepción. De todos modos debería darte la respuesta como aceptada, ya que las demás están erradas.

Comment: @Andrespengineer por eso yo recomiendo la opción que puse en mi respuesta con LINQ, ya que nunca va a lanzar una excepción. Pero tambien como le digo se debe hacer una validación del tamaño siempre para evitar excepciones y sorpresas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar métodos de `LINQ` para obtener los `n` últimos caracteres de un `string`. Para ello, una opción muy sencilla es usar `Reverse` y `Take`. Básicamente, damos de vuelta la cadena, obtenemos 5 caracteres y volvemos a darles la vuelta:

```
var resultado=new string(cadena.Reverse().Take(5).Reverse().ToArray());
```

Esto tiene además una ventaja: si hay menos de 5 caracteres en la cadena, no lanzará ninguna excepción, simplemente devolverá los caracteres que existan.

De todas maneras, no estaría de mas comprobar si la longitud de la cadena es al menos de 5 y en caso contrario devolver por ejemplo una cadena vacía. Algo asi:

```
var resultado=cadena.Length>=5?new string(cadena.Reverse().Take(5).Reverse().ToArray()):"";
```

P.D. El problema con tu código como te han indicado es que el segundo parámetro de [`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) es el número de caracteres que quieres coger. Como en tu caso siempre es 5, puedes ponerlo directamente: `cadena.Substring(10,5)`. Como son siempre los últimos, puedes omitir el último parámetro: `cadena.Substring(10)`. O, si quieres obtener los 5 últimos caracteres sea cual sea el tamaño de la cadena original: `cadena.Substring(cadena.Length-5)`. Ten en cuenta en todos estos casos que debes asegurarte que el tamaño de la cadena original es el adecuado o recibirás un error como el que estás teniendo ahora mismo del tipo `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score -2):

He estado ojeando el código pero creo que si lo que quieres es solamente guardar los últimos 5 dígitos en la base de datos lo que puedes usar es el método `String.Substring(int,int)` en los que las dos variables que le pasas son:

-Índice desde donde empezar(en tu caso 10).

-Tamaño de la cadena(cadena.lenght-1).

Todo esto antes de ingresarlo en la base de datos y con eso obtendrías los 5 últimos dígitos de la cadena o los que quieras. De esta manera veo que puede ser más sencillo.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, lo he puesto asi: string cadena=codigo.Text;
string resultado = cadena.Substring(10, cadena.Length-5);

Comment: sale este error: El índice y la longitud deben hacer referencia a una ubicación en la cadena.
Nombre del parámetro: length'

Comment: el primer parametro int es la posicion, el segundo es la longitud ; posicion + longitud no debe exceder la longitud total del string, recordemos que en c# la longitud inicia desde la posicion 0 

entonces lo mejor seria : 

texto.substring((texto,Length-5),5)

Answer (score -2):

les explico el código,

el método   Substring recupera la subcadena en en una posición de caracteres especificada y continua hasta el final o hasta donde le indiquemos por lo tanto cuando digo "texto.Length" este nos especifica que la cadena contiene 10 posiciones es decir el final de la cadena y si le restamos 5 el metodo substring inicia en justo antes de la "m" ya que los espacios también cuentan y así se recupera la subcadena desde la posición 5 hasta el final

string texto = "hola mundo"
string retorno = texto.Substring(texto.Length - 5);

//retorno sera "mundo"

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución , considera revisar [answer], edita tu respuesta.

Comment: el método   Substring recupera la subcadena en en una posición de caracteres especificada y continua hasta el final o hasta donde le indiquemos por lo tanto cuando digo "texto.Length" este nos especifica que la cadena contiene 10 posiciones es decir el final de la cadena y si le restamos 5 el metodo substring inicia en justo antes de la "m" ya que los espacios también cuentan y así se recupera la subcadena desde la posición 5 hasta el final

Answer (score -4):

1. Agrega a tus referencias Microsoft.VisualStudio;
2. Using Microsoft.VisualStudio
3. Intenta con:

string cadenaOrigen = "Hola Mundo";

string cadenaResultado = Strings.Right(cadenaOrigen, 5);

Esto te traera como resultado:  "Mundo"

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, me da error :c

Comment: Seguro que `Right` es un método de C#? Si no me equivoco, es un método de Visual Basic, y si quieres usarlo en C# debes referenciar a `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Comment: Tienes toda la razon Mengana.

Comment: Ya edite el post.